# Android VideoView freeze

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a problem that I can only describe: I have an App which plays two different Videos in a `VideoView` when certain buttons are pressed. I am now testing the app on android 2.3. One of the videos is around 100 MB and the other one is around 6 MB. I believe that the issue happens when I'm playing the big file, but I'm not sure.

The issue is that at some point the image shown in the VideoView freezes. From this time on *every* VideoView (even of other Apps) shows the same frozen video frame. It stays like this until I reboot the phone.

Does anybody has an Idea whats wrong?

Comment: Have you googled it to see if anyone else experienced a similar issue? Otherwise, there are too many variables to guess at the core issue: Which device/manufacturer/video format? How much memory, what GPU, etc...? Add those parameters to a google search and see what you can come up with.

Comment: I know. I have googled already but with little results. I was hoping that someone has experienced it yet.

Comment: same issue here, I am playing a list of 5 videos in a loop and in some point in time (it varies from a few minutes to a few hours), the player just freezes and I see only the video place holder. I logged the tot available memory - constant, HeapAllocated, HeapAvailable and HeapFree, they all seem constant during the play.

Comment: @abi I am seeing a very similar issue. Did either of you ever find out what was causing the issue ?